# How to use default Android drawables

Tags: android, drawable

What is the best approach when using default Android drawables? Should I use `android.R.drawable` or should I copy the drawables in my project and use `R.drawable`?

Is there any risk, that in a newer version of Android, some of the default drawables are removed or resized? Or, affect in some negative way, the look of my app? Also, which of the drawables in the Android source code are considered "stable" and should be relied on?

I'd rather not copy the drawables because I think that the look of the app should be consistent with the Android version used. So, for example, for version 1.6 it should use the default Android bitmaps for version 1.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are all the standard Android icon resources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352898/where-are-all-the-standard-android-icon-resources)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you read through any of the discussions on the android development group you will see that they discourage the use of anything that isn't in the public SDK because the rest is subject to extensive change.

Comment: So, basically, anything from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html can be used directly without copying?

Comment: Yes... that is what I would think.

Comment: While it is technically correct that anything not in the SDK can change, there are some things that are highly unlikely to change and if you REALLY need to you can get away with it. The safest thing to do would be to copy the image files you need from the anroid source into your own drawable directory, but this means if they release a new version of Android with different images, your app will look old.

Comment: So don't use it. That's all.

Answer (score 114):

Java Usage example: `myMenuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);`

Resource Usage example: `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"`

Comment: This answers the question exactly.

Comment: but some drawables in my SDK not found in this list!!

Comment: You may be using an older SDK version

Answer (score 35):

As far as i remember, the documentation advises against using the menu icons from android.R.drawable directly and recommends copying them to your drawables folder. The main reason is that those icons and names can be subject to change and may not be available in future releases.

> Warning: Because these resources can change between platform versions, you should not reference these icons using the Android platform resource IDs (i.e. menu icons under android.R.drawable). If you want to use any icons or other internal drawable resources, you should store a local copy of those icons or drawables in your application resources, then reference the local copy from your application code. In that way, you can maintain control over the appearance of your icons, even if the system's copy changes.

from: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html

Comment: I found the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#menuapx

Comment: Hi, So what is the conclusion? To copy or not to copy? This answer sounds convincing to actually copy, but all others advise against it.

Comment: Beware that some drawables are modified by manufacturers, and will look different on different phones. Motoblur uses red highlighting instead of orange, so drawables like checkmarks and buttons (some of which are even in R.drawable) will be inconsistent if you make a copy.

Comment: Yup, also the motoblur menu icons are meant to be on a lighter menu background so if you use a darker background for them on your app that looks fine in all other phones, it's indecipherable with motoblur.

Comment: Google removed that warning from the icon design menu guidelines. Wonder why and whether if the thinking still stands?

Answer (score 20):

Better you copy and move them to your own resources. Some resources might not be available on previous Android versions. [Here is a link](http://androiddrawables.com) with all drawables available on each Android version thanks to @fiXedd

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. However, I am not convinced that I should copy them to my own resources.

Comment: The link is broken. Could you please explain in your answer what was it about or redirect the hyperlink to the right location, please.

Comment: In the provided link, you could see what's available for each version. Just wanted to show how some icons might not be available for old versions. So it's better to copy and move them to your project's resources. This link might help as well: http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

Comment: Or [androiddrawables.com](http://androiddrawables.com/) (lets you view the drawables by android version).

Comment: All links broken :(

Comment: androiddrawables site is down, domain stolen by spammers :(

Answer (score 7):

To use the default android drawable resource, no need copy anything..
you can just import it first with..

```
import android.R;
```

but i will make your own resources will have an error if you want to use it.
The error will be something like:

> R. cannot be resolved

So, I prefer not to `import android.R` but `import *my.own.package*.R;`

then when I can normally use my own resource with `R.drawable.*something*` without error,
and put `android.R.*something_default*` to use the default android resources.

Answer (score 3):

Better to use android.R.drawable because it is public and documented.