# Where are all the standard Android icon resources?

Tags: java, android

I have just started writing my first ever Java/Android application, so forgive the total n00b question.

How do you access the the standard operating system icons such as search icon/menu icon etc? They are not in the res/drawable folder where I would expect to find them. Are they available as part of the SDK or must you download them seperately?

**EDIT**

Maybe you can help me further - I am getting the following error (repeated on):

```
[2011-09-08 19:59:47 - TweetTab] C:\Users\Dan\workspace\TweetTab\res\menu\options_menu.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_search').
```

However, the icon is not empty, the xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search"/>
</menu>
```

Am I missing something?

**SOLVED**

I changed `android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"` to `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"` and it could then find the icon.

Comment: I'm going to +1 @jacktrades recommendation... caveat though: I made it :)

Comment: where was this documented? Could you link to the refs that detail that syntax?  Very useful, but very random

Comment: Related post - [How to use default Android drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3201643/465053)

Answer (score 74):

You can acces them via `android.R.drawable.*` or in xml by `@android:drawable/something`.

Comment: and they are part of the sdk, you do not have to download them separately

Comment: but you have to know the name to use them. your answer is not right

Comment: This answer is correct regarding how to USE the resources in code,  additionally see my answer below which answers WHERE the images are via links to how to lookup the names and preview the images of the various android.R.drawable images included with the android SDK

Answer (score 14):

I installed the Android SDK for Eclipse on Windows.

Now I can find all ressources under "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-9\data\res..."

Answer (score 6):

it is now possible to use vector assets to generate standard (or customised) icons for android.

- Add 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta3' to your build.gradle file. (The stable version will be out in the coming weeks).
- Add a vector asset by right-clicking res/drawable/ > New > Vector Asset. Android Studio provides a built-in viewer for you to pick your drawable.
- Reference your icon like you usually do. Eg: android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_24dp"

Comment: EDIT: Gradle 1.5.0 is stable and supports the same.

Comment: Seems the provided link: http://blog.grafixartist.com/using-vector-assets-for-icons-in-android-studio-1-4/ is dead.

Answer (score 6):

try this instead:

```
         android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
```

Answer (score 3):

A lot of them can be found in `android.R.drawable` but not all are publicly accessible

Answer (score 1):

You can find the android.R.drawable images in your local SDK folder.  (Tested using Android Studio 3.0)

First have a look at the docs for the names of the drawables here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

Second either search your drive for one of those image names.png or type in the name of any of them into your Android Studio activity and right click (goto declaration) on it to view the image.  Then you can also right click that image to copy the path.  Then open that folder and look at all the PNG's there.

Example on windows 10: android.R.drawable.star_big_on is located in user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-25/data/res/drawable-hdpi/star_big_on.png

(Note also on windows AppData is a hidden folder so you may need to set your windows explorer to show hidden if you are clicking to open each folder)

Also if you need to see material design icons / descriptions this is a good place to look: https://material.io/icons

Answer (score 0):

Someone may see this page useful for getting those icons... http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: This is not a real answer. Comment these things please.

Comment: This actually helped me. Its really hard getting System icons in 2015  https://www.google.com/design/icons/

Answer (score 0):

For those of you in the Visual Studio/Xamarin Android camp, you can view and add the standard Material icons pretty easily using the following plugin:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nikainteristi.Materialiconsgenerator

I've used it a few times in my projects.