# Where can I find Android's default icons?

Tags: android, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standard Android menu icons, for example refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687027/standard-android-menu-icons-for-example-refresh)

Where can I find the name of the default Android menu icons (like refresh or compose)?

The code below has an error stating that the resource is not public

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/preference"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Comment: [Material Design Icons Index](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/), download from [GitHub](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons).

Comment: Link shared in Jagdeep Singh's answer is perfect answer. Its by Google itself: https://design.google.com/icons/

Comment: Related post - [How to use default Android drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3201643/465053) & [Where are all the standard Android icon resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7352898/465053)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
\path-to-your-android-sdk-folder\platforms\android-xx\data\res
```

Comment: but i cannot find Android.Resource.Drawable.Information_icon icon file in there. where can i find it?

Comment: in Windows: `C:\Users\your-user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-XX\data\res`

Comment: any way to view these xml files as images and scan them rapidly like in a photo gallery?

Comment: for me this works, E:\SoftWares\Android-SDK\platforms\android-26\data\res\drawable-hdpi

Answer (score 97):

you can use

```
android.R.drawable.xxx
```

(use autocomplete to see whats in there)

Or download the stuff from http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Comment: Too bad there's not an index page with thumbnails of each, like with Bootstrap or Glyphicons.

Comment: Be careful with this. The icons can change or disappear in different android versions. Adding them as icons to your app is always safest.

Comment: That is for programmatically approach, how can I use this in `xml` ?

Comment: @RoCk You can use `@android:drawable/...` in the src property of your view.

Answer (score 37):

You can find the default Android menu icons here  - <strike>[link is broken now](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/).</strike>

**Update**: 
   You can find Material Design icons [here](https://www.google.com/design/icons/).

Comment: This answer was flagged as "low quality". You can try adding some more text next time.

Comment: Read the question. According to question it is enough.

Comment: I know, it was flagged by the automatic StackOverflow system, this is why I'm telling you, so next time your answers won't get flagged :)

Comment: Please don't change your answering style just to conform to some broken automatic system; the system needs to be fixed if the answer is indeed good enough.

Comment: The provided link is broken.

Comment: @Hannah Updated the answer.

Comment: This IS PERFECT answer. The link has got almost all the icons.