# Default Android player icons?

Tags: android

Does Android have default play/pause control icons?

I found [Where can I find Android's default icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185722/where-can-i-find-androids-default-icons) , there are many folders here. I searched for "play", "pause" in file names and nothing showed up.

Where can I find Android's default playback control icons?

Comment: u min u want to a icon assets play and push ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System default icons listed:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

And call the resource in this way:
android.R.drawable.ic_media_play or .ic_media_pause, enjoy autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

You can find google's material design icons [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons), in `av` folder you should find play and pause.

If you're using Android Studio and you're ok with vector drawables, right click on `drawable` folder -> new -> vector assets -> select "material icon" -> click on "icon" -> choose the one you want, should be looking again in "av" folder

If by chance you're using [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), they distribute icons in their ui module