# How do you use Android R Drawables without using XML?

Tags: android, resources, system, drawable, r.java-file

http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/
I want to be able to use these drawables inside my projects, but my projects are generated at runtime. I only use XML to define new activities, because quite frankly, I hate working with XML from within java. I'm looking for a mathod similar to this. One that doesn't use any XML to 'findByID' the component it needs. Thank you. 
Drawable foo = new Drawable(bar);

Comment: What do you mean by "my projects are generated at runtime"?

Comment: Instead of using FindById (Button) you use Button derp = new Button(context);
or... instead of setContentView(R.some.thing) you use setContentView(new Scrollview(....));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is it that you are looking for? You want to build activities at runtime without XML? Do you want to just be able to manipulate the android drawables?

Well this is how you use the android drawables:

[How to use default Android drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201643/how-to-use-default-android-drawables)

Comment: @Pangamma - If one of the answers solves your problem, it's good form to mark the answer as a solution (by clicking the check mark next to the answer).