# @drawable vs @android:drawable in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any difference between

```
android:src="@andriod:drawable/filename"
```

and

```
android:src="@drawable/filename"
```

I can access the same resource in this way in xml file. What's the difference?

Comment: @andriod:drawable/ are default Android drawables check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201643/how-to-use-default-android-drawables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a whole lot of difference:

```
android:src="@android:drawable/filename"
```

It allows you to only access those drawables which are provided by the android package, and:

```
android:src="@drawable/filename"
```

allows you to access those drawables that you put inside your app's drawable folder

Comment: Does it mean something inside drawable-hdpi kinda folder, it can be accessed via "@android" and those resources which has been copied in drawable folder can be accessed via "@drawable"  @Sarthak?

Comment: @Jeet that question has a really big answer to it, but to put it short:

suppose you have an image that you are displaying in an ImageView now every device has different resolutions so your image might appear properly in some device and might appear blurred in some, so android has different drawable folders of which main ones are: mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi

Now you put your same image in those folders with different resolutions of the image, android automatically compares the devices resolution at runtime and displays the image from the relevant folder.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between both calls is simple

```
android:src="@andriod:drawable/filename"
```

This gives access to in-built drawable files in your android sdk.

and

```
android:src="@drawable/filename"
```

This gives access to in drawable files which are used for project ie, drawable in `res` folder of project folder in your android sdk.

While using the First one we can find out that it will not show the names of any drawable in `res` folder of project. And when you use second one it will not show names of in built drawable

You can find all in-built resources (drawable,animations etc) used by your API level in SDK

```
<your_path>\sdk\platforms\<api-level>\data\res
```

eg `<your_path>\sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res` this will show all in-built resource under API-19

Answer (score 1):

yes both are very different.

`android:src="@andriod:drawable/filename"` this is a resource where u can get the android inbuilt resources.

`android:src="@drawable/filename"` this is the resource where you add ur own resources and access.

Answer (score 1):

The notation is

```
@[package:]drawable/filename
```

The resources you access with your first line are drawables embedded in the android project. If you don't define the package you access the resources from the res folder in your app. Those are not the same resources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , of course. There is difference between"@andriod:drawable/filename" & @drawable/filename.

```
"@android:drawable/filename"
```

is provided by the system .The resources are contained in your SDK.you can explore the path of resource to check.

```
"@drawable/filename"
```

is our own resources , like app's icon , background & more.