# Android Dialog shadow?

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, android-studio-2.2

I would like to ask someone on how to add shadow on android dialog?

Is there a way to do this thing? Because currently i have a dialog box but it is plane and no shadow style.

Hope someone can help me.

[image]

Here is my activity_dialog.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.bloxofcode.toggle.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@color/colorHeaderDialog"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/select_gender"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|left"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_name"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ToggleButton
                android:text="ToggleButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toggleButtonMale"
                android:textOn=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:focusable="false"
                android:background="@drawable/check_male"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:text="ToggleButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toggleButtonFemale"
                android:textOn=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:focusable="false"
                android:background="@drawable/check_male"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAccept"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Accept"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:background="@color/colorDialogOK"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: whats current api version?

Comment: show us AlertDialog code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

define new theme

```
 <style name="dialog_theme">
 ...
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light</item>
 ...
 </style>
```

then assign this theme to your dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.dialog_theme);
```

if that drawable didn't work try this one:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

hope this woks.

Comment: hi sir thanks for your respond, but how can i have abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light?? it is built-in in android? or do i need to create it on image editor like photoshop?

also for the second option, where should i insert it?

thanks for your patience sir..

Comment: These are android default drawables and they may be different from version to version you should use android prefix to reference them. check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201643/how-to-use-default-android-drawables

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bloxofcode.teststyle.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @NPE Hi sir i am correct to implement it like this??