# Android, Is there any reference to see what are Android default icons and images?

Tags: android, image, icons

When I want to design UI and I need to know what are predefined icons. I searched net including http://developer.android.com/design/index.html but I didn't find complete repository about this.

I found http://www.darshancomputing.com/android/1.5-drawables.html but its information is too old.

Is there any source that collects all predefined icons and images?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see them if you go to your Android folder (containing the android-sdk, tools, etc.)

`android-sdk/platforms/[CHOOSE ANDROID VERSION]/data/res/` and all of your icons are there.

**Versions info:**

- `android-7` in the `platforms` folder, for example, is Android 2.1, while `android-3` is 1.5 (just so you know)

Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687027/standard-android-menu-icons-for-example-refresh) out for more info.

Comment: +1 yep! For a quick reference,**in eclipse** you can also expand the android version referenced in the package explorer and goto `android.jar> res >drawable-<xxx>` and you'll see the file names but you can't open them up.