# How can I use Android native icons in my new app?

Tags: java, android, xml, icons

I'm writing a new Android app.

How can I use Android native icons in it, such as `Edit` pencil icon?

Comment: May helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974548/android-is-there-any-reference-to-see-what-are-android-default-icons-and-images

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you want to use end-user native android-os icon you must use this resources:
for java code:

```
android.R.drawable.ic_input_delete
```

and in your layout xml files:

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
```

and if you want access to physically address of native android icons in your pc go to tthe this address:
android-sdk/platforms/[CHOOSE ANDROID VERSION]/data/res/