# Using ic_menu* icons from Android SDK

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been able to use almost all the icons from the Android SDK, but I couldn't do it for ic_menu_refresh.

I know that I can copy the drawable to my local project and use it this way... But this is now what I want because on differents versions and sizes it will use the same... and this is not what I want.

Why is it now accesible?

Thanks!

Comment: Because Google doesn't want you to rely on that icon being in future releases of SDK. They could choose to remove that icon from the bundle, or just rename it, and that would make your application buggy.

Create your own icon, or copy that one to your drawable folder.

Comment: Have a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687027/standard-android-menu-icons-for-example-refresh

Answer (score 1):

Because this icon is not available in all SDK versions. To add differents refresh icons according SDK, move yours icons in the drawable folder with the API level :

```
drawable-v7
drawable-v8
drawable-v10
drawable-v14
...
```

And you show differents icons for api lvl7,8,10,14 in my example