# Can not access some Android Menu icons via `android.R.drawable.x`

Tags: android, menu, icons, android-resources

Starting from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687027/standard-android-menu-icons-for-example-refresh). I wonder, why some of the menu icons, which I need in my application, even if they are located in SDK folders, can not be accessed via `android.R.drawable` or `@android:drawable/`(in XML)? For example (`ic_menu_refresh`, `ic_menu_login`).
 In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

I think this is an important issue, because they have different sizes(and also design) depending of the android version so it would be difficult for us to store them in our `res` folder.
E.g., In the lower versions

> ldpi are 36x36
>   mdpi are 48x48
>   hdpi are 72x72

In the newer versions

> ldpi are 36x36
>   mdpi are 32x32
>   hdpi are 48x48

If there is no way to access them directly, how should I store them in my `res` folders?

To make different folders like below, is a solution?
E.g. :

```
drawable-mdpi-v10
 drawable-hdpi-v10
 drawable-hdpi-v14 
etc....
```

If so, how many?

Please tell me which is the more suitable way to use these icons, to have the best design in the application for a large variety of devices.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other folder, excepting the default ones,and with the following resources inside

```
drawable-hdpi 48x48
drawable-ldpi 36x36
drawable-mdpi 32x32
```

on Nexus S(Android 4.1.1) and emulator(Android 2.3.3)  looks nice.

I still wonder why I cannot access it directly(via `android.R.drawable`), if any body has any idea.....