# Where could I find android system drawable resources? [android API-7]

Tags: android, drawable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standard Android menu icons, for example refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687027/standard-android-menu-icons-for-example-refresh)

I want to use some android drawables because users already familiar with them.

I've found [this nice site](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/) where I can see the names of resources I need. But I couldn't find some resources inside android.R.drawable.

For example I want to use checkboxes drawables in my application:

[image] [image]

From that site I see that names of those drawables are **btn_check_off** and **btn_check_on** though I don't see such names in my android.R.drawable.

Is it even possible to use any system drawable?

Comment: That's just [btn_check](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/eclair-release/core/res/res/drawable/btn_check.xml) which has those states internally. You may be unable to use the state drawables directly.

Comment: @zapl I have this specific task when I need to display checkbox as ImageView. I need checkbox in the ListView item, and it's not working like list item with checkbox in it but everything OK when I add ImageView which looks like checkbox.

Comment: In case you don't want to do it with `ImageView`s: a ListView with checkboxes is possible without manually setting images, http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php & http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525 - especially the `descendantFocusability` parameter in the layout can be required

Comment: @zapl Thank! This is what I was searching first but without success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of assets can be found there:

```
<SDK>\platforms\android-<VERSION>\data\res\
```

so, assuming you got all it fetched, in your case:

```
<SDK>\platforms\android-7\data\res\
```

however not all elements are full available via direct reference. Just copy/modify what you need and add to your project