# Add "menu" on every listview item

Tags: android

I'm developing this app, which has a listview in it, but I want to add the "three-dot" icon in the corner, and when you press it, an awesome menu will popup. Like this in the Google Play app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7LhJ.jpg

I've seen many apps that have it, so it could'nt be that hard? I have googled a lot, but to be honest, I don't know really what I should google on. This must probably be the shortest & dumbest question on Stackoverflow, but I didn't really know what my other options was.

I have a thought that it may just be an spinner that somehow is hidden and when you press the three-dot icon it'll just pop up in an awesome way, or is this implemented in the Android SDK?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know how they do it or if this is the best way but you could create the `overflow` icon (3 dots) and use a `PopupMenu` for this. This was added in `API 11` so it wouldn't work on older versions but if you are targeting `API >= 11` then I think this would be a good option for you. I use it in a custom "actionbar".

If this isn't awesome enough for you then you can also use `PopupWindow` which has been around since `API 1`

[PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

[PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

Comment: Well, one more question. I don't seem to find the overflow icon, neither do i find how to create it somehow in the listview. Do you know how I can do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had one custom made when we had all of our icons redone but I believe they should be in the `sdk` somewhere. Sorry, I can't tell you where but check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687027/standard-android-menu-icons-for-example-refresh)

Comment: @GuiceU You can download them here as vector grafics: http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html
Just scroll down to the section named "Action Bar Icon Pack"

Comment: With support lib(v7) you can use PopupMenu for API < 11

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you are looking for is a [Popup Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu)