# How to create a simple drop down list/ListView programmatically in android

Tags: java, android

I want to create a simple drop down list/`listview` like in below image. It should generate programmatically without using any xml layout.

**NOTE** : **I am not using a spinner in here . Also I want to open it when I click on the ImageView next to the Switch.**

[image]

I have no idea about this .

Have any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a drop-down list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377361/how-to-create-a-drop-down-list)

Comment: Why does it have to be programatically?

Comment: @MidasLefko : I added above to rows dynamically . So other components should be generated dynamically .

Comment: without using xml will make this complex, why do you need it to be done programmatically?

Comment: what are the other components?

Answer (score 4):

not perfect, but it works ;)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button);
            popupMenu.getMenu().add("Edit");
            popupMenu.getMenu().add("Delete");
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getTitle().toString()) {
                        case "Edit" :
                            //execute "edit" action
                            break;
                        case "Delete" :
                            //execute "delete" action
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But I have a problem with using this . Last popup menu is loading above the button . How could I stop it . I've tried setting Gravity , but it didn't work .

Comment: Please check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565481/add-a-drop-down-menu-for-each-item-of-a-custom-listview

Comment: @Barrier Glad to be helpful! If there is enough space below the anchor button? From documentation: "The popup will appear below the anchor if there is room, or above it if there is not."

Comment: @Barrier If so - add some space below list's last view. Need more info to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I use [`PopupMenu`'s](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) for this. See also [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu). The guide explains how to use the `PopupMenu` with an xml menu resource.

In your case you would attach a click listener to the ImageView. That listener would then create a PopupMenu using the ImageView as an anchor. Like this: `PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(imageView.getContext(), imageView);`

At this point since  you need dynamic menu items you have the following options:

1. You can call PopopMenu.getMenu() and manually populate it with MenuItems
2. You can create an xml menu resource and then adjust/hide ones that need to be changed

Comment: Thanks I will try on this and inform you later.

Answer (score 2):

```
Just try to check and implement it

    PopupMenu overflowPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), finalOverflow); 
    overflowPopupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_overflow_options, overflowPopupMenu.getMenu()); 

    overflowPopupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
         public boolean onMenuItemClick(android.view.MenuItem item) {
                   switch (item.getItemId()) {
                          case R.id.edit: 
                               break;
                           case R.id.delete:  
                                break; 
                     }
                           return true;
                 }
   });
  overflowPopupMenu.show();
```

popup_overflow_options.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit" 
        android:title="@string/edit"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete" 
        android:title="@string/delete"/> 
</menu>
```