# Popup Menu issue in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-menu, popupmenu

I am new to Android and I am creating Listview Popup Menu. But I am having it's `width` and `height` problem. The Popup Menu can take more height and width. There are many questions in SO, but none of these helped me.

To **create Popup Menu** I have tried the **following method**.

**1 ]**   Using **Popup menu** with the code below:

```
 private void showPopupMenu(View view){
        Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.PopupMenu);
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper,view);

        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu,popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.show();

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
            @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.install:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ViewAllRelationActivity.this,EditRelativeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.addtowishlist:
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

It gives this **output** :

[image]

**2 ]**  Using **ContextMenu** it displays the following **output** :

We can maintain **width and height in ContextMenu** But it **always show in Centre** `not each row of our Listview Data`.

[image]

But I want `below Image type Popup menu`. **Width and height are small**.

[image]

Please provide the solution for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22311108/5093666  may be this answer will helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

You can add those options programmatically without using xml file as below, may be this could help you out.

Here ONE and TWO is showing the index for options which you are giving in popup menu. Like on 1st position **EDIT POST** on 2nd position **REMOVE POST** etc.

1) on image click open popup menu:

```
private final static int ONE = 1;
private final static int TWO = 2;

PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.img_detail_information_options));
popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, ONE, Menu.NONE, getResources().getString(R.string.detail_information_edit_post));
popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, TWO, Menu.NONE, getResources().getString(R.string.detail_information_remove_post));
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
popupMenu.show();
```

Comment: ONE and TWO not found and also popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this); giving me error.

Comment: ONE and TWO is showing the index for options menu, you can set int number in place of ONE and TWO, and popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this); is giving error because you've not implemented PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener in your activity or you can just simply replace that with this one popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener());

Comment: edit the Answer and write full description I can't understand you.

Comment: I Tried popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this); line give me red signal.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using adapter, you can put in getView(...) method in adapter

```
    imvMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPopupMenu(act,v);
        }
    });
```

and put method

```
private void showPopupMenu(Activity act, View view){
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(act,view);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

in your adapter class.

Note: act is Activity you have to bind when create constructor adapter, example:

```
public YourAdapter(Activity act, ArrayList<ItemOfYourModel> data){
    this.data = data;
    this.act = act;
}
```

In Activity, you can code:

```
ArrayList<ItemOfYourModel> listData = new ArrayList<ItemOfYourModel>();
listData.add(new YourItemOfYourModel(...));
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(this,listData);
```

Comment: How to bind act in adapter please describe widely?

Comment: @Harshad, which adapter and activity have you used? And you used listview or recyclerview?

Comment: listview and BaseAdapter

Comment: @Harshad, see my new updated answer. Hope to help you

Answer (score 2):

You can use ListPopupWindow to get what you want to achieve. You can set the more option icon or menu icon as anchor for the popup window.

```
ListPopupWindow mListPopupWindow;
mListPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(this, null);
mListPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
mListPopupWindow.setAnchorView(menuIcon);
mListPopupWindow.setHeight(200);
mListPopupWindow.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
mListPopupWindow.show();
```

You will get what you want.

Comment: What problem are you facing this?

Comment: It display center I want it dynamic ?

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. It will show with respect to the anchor you specify. If i can manage i will post working code for you.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution of this I think is to use PopupWindow ,you can control every thing of it and it is very easy to create the menu you want.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play uses the `Holo` theme for `PopupMenu`. You can do the same by creating a custom `style` in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Your custom attributes must be put here. This is optional, but the parent must not be changed -->
</style>
```

And then change the `PopupMenu` style in your code:

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.PopupMenuStyle);
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper,view);
```

Comment: I Used this But Menu Display in the Center like ContextMenu I want it each Row of ListView.

Comment: You must be setting this on the whole view. Instead, add a button like Google play has in the list item. Then it will not appear in the center.

Comment: How can I set Width and Height is Give My First Conditon of Question.

Comment: For PopupMenu, you can't. The white background for each item you see in the menu is drawable of a fixed size. The size is the ideal size of a menu, but if you still want to change the size, use PopupWindow.