# Implement dropdown submenu inside Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Need to implement dropdownmenu inside Recyclerview. while pressing on the imagebutton. Is it possible to implement like this.
here is my recyclerview 
[image]

Dropdown menu is look like this

[image]

Is anyone face this before. Anyone have solution. Please help me, this is first project. Thanks

Comment: here is the same question with accepted answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22311108/5212133

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar its actual works in listview but i'm using recyclerview. But i try this not working for me

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar Sry man its works Thanks