# How add PopupMenu in listview android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

how to add option menu in `listview` like this screenshot. it's taken from `GooglePlay`
anybody have sample code or reference link like this screenshot 
 [image]

Comment: please explain.. why you down vote my question

Comment: It's just a [`PopupMenu`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) anchored to a simple `ImageView` (or `ImageButton`). There's also a compat version in the v7 support library.

Comment: @MH. how we can add in cardview...??

Comment: Refer this may solve your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16427480 and https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Menus-and-Popups and http://stackoverflow.com/a/22311108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save time you can use this [cardview library](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) by [gabrielemariotti](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti). It has build in card exactly what you wanted, so you can use it directly in your code.

Just add gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.1.0'
}
```

The rest you can follow from [the documentation](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md).

Answer (score 1):

One simple and quick solution:
Add image to your List item and perform on click event on it:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;




PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
popup.getMenu().add("AAA");
popup.getMenu().add("BBB");
popup.getMenu().add("CCC");
popup.getMenu().add("CCC");
popup.show();
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    //perform action here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option,menu);
    return true;
}
```

}