# default 'show menu' icon on android

Tags: android, layout, icons, android-resources

I have an app that features a grid view. For each item in the grid view I want to provide a context menu, much like you see on the play store

I would like to use the built in android menu icon, but I can't find it anywhere in android.R.drawable, like one might expect it to be. Where, therefore, can I find the icon so I can set it as a drawable in my grid view item.

According to Dmags' answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687027/standard-android-menu-icons-for-example-refresh) Google advises that

> you should not reference these icons using the Android platform resource IDs (i.e. menu icons >under android.R.drawable).

(though the page linked no longer appears to contain this warning)

I am puzzled as to why this advice would be given? I would want the design to be consistent with the OS it is running on. If Android 5 decides to have an image of a lemon to display the menu, I'd want my app to also use the same image of a lemon to show sub menus.

So can anybody either give me a good reason as to why I should be creating my own graphic rather than use the default Android graphic, or give me the location in which the menu graphic can be found?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your android-sdk folder:
C:\Program Files\android\sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light.png

I think this might be the one you are looking for.

It is not a good practice to use drawable direct from @android:... because android is an open-source platform and every customer (like Samsung or the cyanogen mod crew) can build their own version of it without the drawable u are using. so you can get a null pointer exception. The better way is to copy the drawable from the android sdk directly into your project.

Comment: wouldn't it break the entire OS though, if the menu icon wasn't included in a build?

Comment: if I wanted to use this drawable directly, how would I go about it? contextget.Resources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.xxxx) doesn't contain ic_menu_moreovrflow.

Comment: Please copy it, some drawables are private! And could you mark my answer as right and give a upvote.